# How to add custom class to ng2-popover

Tags: css, angular5, popover

I am using ng2-popover. I have 3-5 popovers in my html page. But for one popover I need to add some styles. How can I add that? 
Below is the code I am using for the popover

```
<popover-content class="popovertext" #mypopover popover-class="popover-no-margin" placement="bottom" [closeOnClickOutside]="true" class="dropdown-header">
    <div class="list-side-by-side">
         some data
    </div>
</popover-content>
<img class="imgss" [popoverAnimation]="true"  [popover]="myPopover" [popoverOnHover]="true" src="assets/img/ABC.png" width=36px height=36px>
```

Comment: I have tried popover-class="custompopover" instead of popover-class="popover-no-margin"

Comment: What about `class="popovertext custompopover"`?

Comment: No. It is not working

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz example? Hard to say what's wrong just by looking at this

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nnaet7 Here I cannot see popover working? I have added the dependency too